# Having trouble with this recursive function

Tags: python

See the function below. What I want this to do is take any string I send it, search for the '[' and ']' characters. If they exist, this portion of text is split out, the brackets are removed and it's turned into a dict. I then try to match any of the values from the dict to the attrs list. If there is a match, this value is then inserted back into the original string, and we call the function again with the new string. The conditional then checks if there are more brackets, and if not, the new string is returned.

But when I run the code, the value I get back for text1 is None. I put the print statement in the else clause to see what's coming through there, and the new string is printed as I would expect, but this string isn't getting passed back in the return statement.

When I call the function with text2, which is an identical string to the one I'm expecting text1 to hold, the value is indeed the original string assigned to string2.

```
import ast

string1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit [{'do':'said', 'eiusmod':'tempor', 'incididun':'ut'}]"

string2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"



def formatter(content):
    if content.find('[') >= 0:
        attrs = ['do', 'fum']
        ind, indend = content.find('['), content.find(']')
        choice = ast.literal_eval(content[ind+1:indend])
        for attr in attrs:
            for key, value in choice.iteritems():
                if attr == key:
                    new_choice = choice[key]
                    new_string = content[:ind] + new_choice + content[indend+1:]
                    formatter(new_string)
    else:
        return content

text1 = formatter(string1)
text2 = formatter(string2)
print text1
print text2
```

Comment: Some general advice: `content.find('[') >= 0` is ugly, use `'[' in content` instead. Also, don't abuse tuple unpacking. Move the `ind` and `indend` assignments into separate lines. Eventually, if you end up making the whole body of a loop conditional, it's better to use `if not condition: continue` to avoid the extra level of indentation of the actual body. Even if you use 100- or 120-char lines, horizontal space is valuable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tweaked your code a little bit to make it clearer what's happening:

```
import ast

string1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit [{'do':'said', 'eiusmod':'tempor', 'incididun':'ut'}]"

string2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"



def formatter(content):
    print "content: %s" % content
    if content.find('[') >= 0:
        print "running if"
        attrs = ['do', 'fum']
        ind, indend = content.find('['), content.find(']')
        choice = ast.literal_eval(content[ind+1:indend])
        for attr in attrs:
            for key, value in choice.iteritems():
                if attr == key:
                    new_choice = choice[key]
                    new_string = content[:ind] + new_choice + content[indend+1:]
                    print "calling formatter with: %s" % new_string
                    formatter(new_string)
                    print "back from recursion"
    else:
        print "running else"
        print content
        return content

print "string1"
print formatter(string1)
print "string2"
print formatter(string2)
```

If you look at the output you'll see that on the first pass a `[` is found, so we descend into the `if` clause. `attr == key` is found to be true in one case, so we descend into the inner if clause, and then trigger the recursive call to `formatter(new_string)`

On that call, there's no `[` so `content` gets returned back up to the original run of formatter... where it's discarded as the output from the recursive call to `formatter()` is not assigned to anything.

The loop eventually ends and execution ends, with nothing being returned from the function.

If you want to bubble `content` back up the call stack, you'll have to catch the return from the recursive call and do something with it. You'll need to return it eventually, but if you want to catch all matches you'll want to do something like build up a list of return values as you iterate over `attrs` and then return the whole list at the end.

Comment: With text1 I'm calling the function with string1. So the first time through the function, the if clause will fire, the brackets will be removed from the string, and then the function is called again with the new string, formatter(new_string) . The new string (in this case) doesn't have any brackets, so the else clause is fired. The reason the if clause has no return statement is I want it to continue running through the if clause until all the brackets are removed.

Comment: Oh look, the function is recursive, so you'd expect it to fire again.

Comment: la la la. I've read the code more better now. The problem is actually that your list of `attrs` doesn't match any of the keys in the dict, so the block inside `if attr == key` never runs.

Comment: oops. I had changed the strings from my original code for this post and forgot to change attrs. It's updated now, my issue persists.

Comment: Odd. Works fine for me:

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit said
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit

Comment: That's your value for text1? I get None for text1

Comment: That's the output I get from running the code you provided.

Comment: But I just realised you said that you "put the print statement in the else clause to see what's coming through there" - so I'm looking at the output from the print statement, while you're running code *without* that print statement and doing something like "print formatter(string1) instead, right?

Comment: Right. Try removing the print statement in the else clause, and adding print statements for text1 and text2 at the bottom. I updated the code like this so you can run as is

Comment: Thanks for that. Apparently there's a lot about handling recursion I don't understand.

Comment: Recursion confuses everyone :)

Comment: So, I've gotten this working by using return formatter(new_string), instead of just calling formatter(new_string)